# Find the number of columns in a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to know if it's possible to find the number of both rows and columns within a table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 245):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name' -- the database
   AND table_name = 'table_name'
```

Comment: Hi i cant under stand, here the information can you please give me the query once again.. 
table name = post
columns = PostingID, PostingDate, Body

Comment: Unless I am confused, you are looking for how many columns are in the table. If you execute the following query, it will return 3 (assuming the only columns are PostingId, PostingDate and Body)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'post'

Comment: I think you need to replace "table_schema" above with "TABLE_CATALOG" for the variable 'database_name'

Comment: In MySQL land (tagged in the question)... A MySQL `database` is equivalent to a `schema` in ANSI SQL and the `table_catalog` is always `def`

Comment: "table_catalog" need to change to "TABLE_SCHEMA"

Answer (score 57):

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_CATALOG = 'Database name' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'table name'
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly, at least with Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 27):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Your_table_name';
```

Note: Your_table_name should be replaced by your actual table name

Comment: Works for MS SQL for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's working (mysql) :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME , count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM information_schema.columns
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Adding `where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public'` works fine for me in Postgresql

Answer (score 6):

Its been little late but please take it from me...

In the editor(New Query) by **select the database object** it can be a table too, if we use the Shortcut Key **Alt+F1** we will get all the information of the object and I think will solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 6):

Using JDBC in Java:

```
    String quer="SELECT * FROM sample2 where 1=2";
    
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(quer);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int NumOfCol=0;
    NumOfCol=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("Query Executed!! No of Colm="+NumOfCol);
```

Comment: This is a good generic approach (RDBMS agnostic). I only suggest to change the query to `SELECT * FROM sample2 WHERE 1=2`. This way, you can get the schema but no data, which could add unneeded overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Well I tried Nathan Koop's answer and it didn't work for me. I changed it to the following and it did work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
```

It also didn't work if I put `USE 'database_name'` nor `WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name' AND table_name' = 'table_name'`. I actually will be happy to know why.

Comment: USE `database_name` sets the default database so you don't need to qualify table names in any statements you issue. Here you do qualify the `columns` table name by saying it's within the information_schema. `table_catalog` exists in mysql purely for the purpose of compatibility with other dbs it's not the same as `table_schema` - see the comments under that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Or use the sys.columns

```
--SQL 2005
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.columns
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'spt_values'
-- returns 6 rows = 6 columns

--SQL 2000
SELECT  *
FROM    syscolumns
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(id) = 'spt_values'
-- returns 6 rows = 6 columns

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.spt_values
    -- 6 columns indeed
```

Comment: select COUNT(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOURTABLENAME>'

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_db_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_CATALOG = 'database_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to find the number of columns in a table just by using 3 simple lines of PHP code.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$query=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql);    
$num=mysqli_num_fields($query);
```

`$num` would return the number of `columns` on a given table in this case.

Hopefully,it would help others.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

Comment: The above mentioned should work to get the number of columns in a specified table in SQL Server Database.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT table_name, COUNT(*) AS column_count
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
    GROUP BY table_name
```

For list of all tables in your schema with their respective column counts.
You may need to add table_catalog = 'your_database_name' condition in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Query to count the number of columns in a table:

```
select count(*) from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'tablename';
```

Replace tablename with the name of the table whose total number of columns you want returned.

Comment: is it also applicable for MYSQL , because i cant execute it

Answer (score 1):

Can get using following sql statement:

```
select count(*) Noofcolumns from SYSCOLUMNS where id=(select id from SYSOBJECTS where name='table_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
    , number = COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`db2 'describe table "SCHEMA_NAME"."TBL_NAME"'`

Comment: While this might solve the original question, it's best to include a description so we know what is going on.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Following query finds how columns in table:-

```
 SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName';
```

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL answer adapted slightly from the [MSDN example for MySqlDataReader.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx):

```
//assumes you've already created a connection, opened it, 
//and executed a query to a reader

while(reader.Read())
{
    Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
    int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

    Console.WriteLine("\nreader.GetValues retrieved {0} columns.",   fieldCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
}
```

Using `MySqlDataReader.FieldCount` will allow you to retrieve the number of columns in the row you've queried.

Answer (score 0):

Since all answers are using `COUNT()`, you can also use `MAX()` to get the number of columns in a specific table as

```
SELECT MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) NumberOfColumnsInTable
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'YourDatabaseNameHere'
      AND 
      TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchemaNameHere'
      AND
      TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableNameHere';
```

See **[`The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.5/en/columns-table.html)**

Answer (score 0):

How about "desc table_name" and count the rows. however,it shows the count in the console output also

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can get a number of table columns using Python 3, sqlite3 and pragma statement:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")    
con.execute("CREATE TABLE tablename (d1 VARCHAR, d2 VARCHAR)")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info(tablename)")
print(len(cur.fetchall()))
```

[Source](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/124403/sqlite3-how-to-see-column-names-for-table)