# Number of column in a table MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the number of columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

I would like to know what is the query which enables to count the number of columns in a table in MySQL.
Something like :

```
SELECT COUNTNUMBEROFCOLUMN(*) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns and information:

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Using the "Data Dictionary" [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) to know the number of columns from a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_table'
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Also

[Find the number of columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

Please read the questions before