# How do you count the number of columns in a table

Tags: mysql

How to find the number of columns in a table.

desc foo (actually mentions the list of columns at the end of the table, as the number of rows it found), but is there a different way to find it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog post.](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/05/mysql-view-metadata-original-source.html)  It shows how to query MySQL metadata, and get the information you want.