# finding the widest columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i  am doing some excercises for practice and i am stuck on this question

Write a query to display a list of the five ‘widest’ tables in the A1_AdventureWorks database. A table is considered to be wide if it has many columns. Do not include any views or system tables.

i have this so far but i am getting some random answers

```
USE A1_AdventureWorks;
SELECT name 
 FROM sys.objects
```

i know i have to use the type function but dont know where to use it 
please assist

Answer (score 2):

Query [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) and [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) joined on `object_id`.

```
select O.name
from sys.objects as O
  inner join sys.columns as C
    on O.object_id = C.object_id
```

To get only user table you need to filter on `where O.type = 'U'`.

To count the number of columns for each table you need to group by `O.name` and add `count(*)` to your field list.

To get the top 5 you should use `select top(5)` and you need to add a `order by count(*) desc` as well.

In SQL Server you can have the same table name in different schema's so you also need to group by `schema_id`.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65157/new

Answer (score 0):

mysql_list_tables to get all table in a database
for references
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  foreach ($row as $item)
  $counter=++$i;
}
```

to get num of rows in a table

Comment: Only use the sys views (e.g. sys.all_columns, sys.all_objects etc)
 this is the restriction

Comment: `all_columns` is an Oracle view. Which DBMS are you **really** using?

Answer (score 0):

the same question exist: [Find the number of columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
  AND table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

UPDATE: you also can use sys.columns:

```
use yourDataBase
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    sys.columns
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'table_name'
```

ANSWER FOR THIS ASSIGNMENT: find 5 widest table query in sqlserver:

```
use yourDataBase

select top 5 OBJECT_NAME(object_id)as name,count(*)as num_of_col from sys.columns 
where object_id in (select object_id from sys.tables)
group by object_id
order by num_of_col desc
```

Comment: Viet Anh
im only supposed to use 
Only use the sys views (e.g. sys.all_columns, sys.all_objects etc)

Comment: still doesnt come up with any answers

Comment: i tried your code but the problem is the answers are wrong im supposed to get like tables with 26 columns and some with like 20 columns

Comment: is it possible to get your email id so i can send you the real answer?

Comment: my email: aic.tovietanh@gmail.com

Comment: I updated the answer. just add order by number of columns desc. It works in my sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  top 5 name
from    (select a.name,count(b.name) 'CNT'
        from    sysobjects a  , syscolumns b
        where   a.xtype =   'U' -- For considering only user tables -- no views or sys tables 
        and     a.id    =   b.id
        group by a.name) a 
order by CNT desc
```