# Get count of columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the number of columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

How can i get the count of columns in my table, searched google through, but can't find a straight answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such information are located in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** you can query a table called `COLUMNS` to get the number of columns in a database.

This query will give you the column count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME' AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(*) totalColumns
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'db_2_a3c3e' AND -- the name of your Database
      table_name = 'table1'           -- the name of your table
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c3e/4)