# In Laravel, Is there a way to find total number of columns in db table?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 5.7, and I am trying to find the total number of columns in mysql db table. Is there any function/way to get the number of columns in table or resultset?

Comment: you can refer to this [blog]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table "question"

Comment: The same question has already been asked and answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table

Comment: Try this `$count = Model::count();`

Comment: @KiranKanzar, need to give this a try, anyways I was looking for a simple function similar to mysqli_num_fields()..

Comment: @KiranKanzar,  "$count = Model::count();" is working, then what for number of columns from a result set?

Comment: @vasim check below my answer, it giving you all column name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a Laravel way of doing it, you can use the `Schema` facade.

For example:

```
Schema::getColumnListing('posts')
```

This would output an array of columns. For example:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "content"
  2 => "created_at"
  3 => "updated_at"
]
```

Then it's just a matter of getting the `count()`.

Or, in one line:

```
return count(Schema::getColumnListing('posts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should have read access from your `information_schama` database from mysql. 
After you perform this request in your Laravel Model

```
SELECT count(*) AS nbr_colomn FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<db_name>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
```

Answer (score 0):

@vasim, Can you try this, and you can get all columns name by simply doing that...

```
Schema::getColumnListing($table);
```