# Count selected rows

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

Can I count rows with this way?

```
    SELECT COUNT(SERVICE_TYPE) INTO N_CNT FROM (
          SELECT RECIPIENT, SERVICE_TYPE, MPS_SWTCH_CD, MPS_FTR_CD1 FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
                                                         WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100 AND
                                                               MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11' AND
                                                               MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count rows like this not columns, the keyword INTO is redundant and If I modify your query it would be like below,

```
SELECT COUNT(SERVICE_TYPE) N_CNT FROM (
          SELECT RECIPIENT, SERVICE_TYPE, MPS_SWTCH_CD, MPS_FTR_CD1 FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
                                                         WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100 AND
                                                               MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11' AND
                                                               MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)a;
```

you can also count without having a subquery

```
SELECT Count(*) N_CNT
FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100 AND
MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11' AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033;
```

Comment: The `INTO` keyword is not redundant if that is really used inside a stored procedure in PL/SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Noted with thanks, a new addition to me since I'm not much aware of PL/SQL syntax literacy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, your statement is for counting rows. If you want to count the columns of your table try something like this.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name' -- the name of your database
   AND table_name = 'table_name' -- the table you want to count columns in
```

Comment: It's actually count rows. Not columns.

Comment: Saw your edit just after I posted. Just ignore it then.