# How to retrieve the count of columns for a table in SQL and combine it with another SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need the count of columns of a table, in below SQL I am getting the desired output, but I also need the count of columns of that 'PAYMENT' table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRowCount,     
MAX(MODIFIEDUTC) AS newMODIFIEDUTC, 
MIN(MODIFIEDUTC) AS oldMODIFIEDUTC, 
MAX(CREATEDUTC) AS newCREATEDUTC, 
MIN(CREATEDUTC) AS oldCREATEDUTC, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(MODIFIEDUTC), GETDATE()) AS Freshness 
FROM NAVI.PAYMENT;
```

How do I get columns count without disturbing above sql query. I need to run this query in SNOWFLAKE and also in Microsoft SQL server management studio.

Comment: Hope you will find a clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross-platform query would look like

```
select count(*)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_schema = 'NAVI' and table_name = 'PAYMENT';
```

To incorporate in existing query you would simply do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRowCount,     
..., (
  select count(*)
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  where table_schema = 'NAVI' and table_name = 'PAYMENT'
) as ColumnCount
FROM NAVI.PAYMENT;
```

Comment: I want to use this query in the above sql query I posted, how do I use both in one single query.

Comment: You would use it in a sub-query.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: See edit in answer above

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only, use `sys.columns` instead.

Comment: The OP mentions running in Snowflake and (until question was edited) had tagged `mysql` also - otherwise for sql-server only it would have been `sys.columns`